# TypeError: _vm.removeProductFromCart is not a function in vue/vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to delete an item from the cart. So I should be able to delete the item with the id of the cart.
I have a cartHelper and there I defined my api call:

```
removeFromCart: function (id, callback = undefined) {
        return apiHelper.deleteRequest(
            `/carts/${this.cookieValue}/remove-item`,
            (response) => {
                document.cookie = `${this.cartCookieName}=${response.data.attributes.cart_guid};`;
                if (callback) { callback(response); }
            },
            {
                id: id
            }
        )
    },
```

And later I am calling this function in my Cart component:

```
methods: {
    removeFromCart(id) {
        cartHelper.removeFromCart(id, () => {
            this.$store.dispatch('removeProductFromCart', id)
        });
    },
},
```

And I defined my action like in the below:

```
export const removeProductFromCart = ({ commit }, id) => {
    commit('REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART', id);
}
```

And here is my mutation:

```
export const REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART = (state, id) => {
    state.cart = state.cart.filter(item => {
        return item.id !== id;
    })
}
```

But as soon as I click the button, where I am calling removeFromCart in my Cart component, I am getting "TypeError: _vm.removeProductFromCart is not a function" and I couldn't figure out the reason. If you can help me, that would be great.

Edited version---------
Here is my state:

```
export default {
    cart: {
        "attributes": {
            "items": [],
        }
    }
```

And my index.js for store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

import state from "./state";
import * as getters from './getters';
import * as mutations from "./mutations";
import * as actions from "./actions";

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
});

}
```

Comment: `removeProductFromCart` is exported, but I can't see if it is in actions block of store ?

Comment: What do you mean? I couldnt understand. So what do you think I should do?

Comment: Can you show `store` setup ?

Comment: Try to `commit` **REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART** in **removeFromCart** callback instead of dispatching **removeProductFromCart**

Comment: Could you write how? I dont think I understood

Comment: Instead of `this.$store.dispatch('removeProductFromCart', id)` write `this.$store.commit('REMOVE_PRODUCT_FROM_CART ', id)`

Comment: removeProductFromCart is not a function, still I am getting this error

Comment: It's like **this** in callback is is bound to the parent context instead of Vue instance, change arrow function to anonymous `cartHelper.removeFromCart(id, function () {
            this.$store.dispatch('removeProductFromCart', id) });`

Comment: Still same: vue.esm.js:1897 TypeError: _vm.removeProductFromCart is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have been calling `removeProductFromCart` on @click event which does not exist in you methods. Try calling `removeFromCart` on @click event.